# Having difficulties with pg_query(); in php

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Currently I am using Postgres with PHP. I'm writing an interface where a user can fill in a user, so it gets added to the total record of users in the database. (Very simple).

Recently I've been having alot of trouble getting the queries to work. Escaping seems to be required all the time. Just the query itself between double quotes isnt enough anymore.

I'm having trouble with the following query;

```
$query = pg_query($dbconnection,"INSERT INTO clients('clientid', 'name', 'ipaddress',     'status') VALUES ('$clientid', '$name', '$ipaddress', '$status' ");
```

This doesn't work. I guess there's more escaping needed. Is there any third party tool available to check if these postgres syntaxes are valid or not?

If not, how can I exactly turn this query into a useable one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pg_query_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) to handle escaping and avoid SQL injection:

```
$query = pg_query_params(
  $dbconnection,
  'INSERT INTO clients(clientid, name, ipaddress,status) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4);', // placeholders
   array($clientid, $name, $ipaddress, $status) // content
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   Try this
   $query = pg_query($dbconnection,
   "INSERT INTO clients(clientid, name, ipaddress,status) VALUES ('$clientid', '$name', '$ipaddress', '$status' ");
```

Comment: It would be helpful to suggest why you think this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = pg_query($dbconnection, "INSERT INTO clients(clientid, name, ipaddress,status) VALUES ('$clientid', '$name', '$ipaddress', '$status')");
```

should do the work. Note no quotes around the field names and the closing parenthesis after the `VALUES`.