# Difficulty processing data from jQuery post to pg_query();

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, php-pgsql

Having the following difficulty.

I'm currently creating a form. This form is made in HTML and controlled by jQuery.

The form code is as following;

```
<div id="form">
        <form>
            <label>ID :</label>
            <input type="text" id="clientid" /><br /><br />
            <label>Name :</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" /><br /><br />
            <label>IP Address :</label>
            <input type="text" id="ipaddress"/><br /><br />
            <label>Status :</label>
            <input type ="text" id ="status" />
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Insert" /><br /><br /><br />
            <label id="response"></label>
        </form>
```

Now, this form picks up user data, and gets processed by the following jQuery script;

```
// Start jQuery script
// jQuery for dynamic adding without complete page reloads
//Wait for document readiness

$('document').ready(function() {
    // Define submit button and action
    $('#button').click(function() {

        // Assign variable
        if ($('#clientid').val() == "") {
            alert("Enter Client ID");
            return false;
        } else {
            var clientid = $('#name').val();
        }

        // Assign variable
        if ($('#name').val() == ""){
            alert("Enter Client full name");
            return false;
        } else {
            var name =$('#name').val();                        
        }

        // Assign variable
        if ($('#ipaddress').val() == "") {
            alert("Enter Client owned IP address");
            return false;
        } else {
            var ipaddress = $('#ipaddress').val();
        }

        // Assign variable
        if ($('#status').val() == "") {
            alert("Enter client status");
            return false;
        } else {
            var status = $('#status').val();
        }

        // When variables are known, continue processing and POST'ing
        // Posting to seperate PHP file to complete
        jQuery.post("processing/addC.php", {
            clientid: clientid,
            name: name,
            ipaddress: ipaddress,
            status: status
        },

        function(data, textStatus) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $('#response').html("Insert successful!");
                $('#response').css('color', 'green');
            } else {
                $('#response').html("Insertion failure. Please try again or restart.");
                $('#response').css('color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This code obviously passes the variables through a POST to addC.php.

addC.php contains the following code:

```
<?php

// Get current connection
include 'dbconnect.php';

$clientid = $_POST['clientid'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$ipaddress = $_POST['ipaddress'];
$status = $_POST['status'];

$query = pg_query_params(
  $dbconnection,
  'INSERT INTO clients(clientid, name, ipaddress,status) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4);', 
   array($clientid, $name, $ipaddress, $status)
);                         

if(pg_affected_rows($query)>0){
    echo "1";
}else{
    echo "2";
}

?>
```

The desired result of this code is the if-statement returning a 1, so the jQuery can create a nice green message saying the database insertion went correct.

Now, as I validated the pg_query(); syntax to be correct, there must be something wrong in this code itself. What seems to be the problem here?

**EDIT:**

*Following error;*
**Warning**:  pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "michael" in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/LoginHQ/processing/addC.php** on line **18**

Comment: If any of the 4 fields didn't fit into the destination column, how would you know? What stands out in the php code is the lack of error checking and logging.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the comment. What is, according to you, the most efficient way to error check?

Comment: when the return value of `pg_query_params` is null, output `pg_last_error()` on an error channel. If your project doesn't already have an error logging strategy, just use php's `error_log()`. If you have access to postgres log files, you may peek into them too.

Comment: Got the following  error;

<b>Warning</b>:  pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: &quot;michael&quot; in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/LoginHQ/processing/addC.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />

Comment: so you've found the problem. _michael_ cannot go into a column that's supposed to contain an integer number.

Comment: Problem is, I don't really know where that integer declaration comes from. Database states the column as 'text' and the HTML form does too.

Comment: It' not just one column. All 4 columns and 4 values must correspond.

Comment: Alright;
ClientID = bigserial;
name = text;
ipaddress = cidr;
status = integer. Are these data types correct? Now I'm kind of thinking of changing the bigserial..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having difficulties with pg\_query(); in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293045/having-difficulties-with-pg-query-in-php)

Comment: you are inserting a string to an integer field

Answer (score 0):

```
invalid input syntax for integer: "michael"
```

It means that column has type integer, but you try insert string